# What happens if a Prism Module crashes? Is the application still stable?

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, prism

I've read a little on Prism and think it's an attractive technology for a program I want to write.  I'm looking for a stable platform that can host several modules and maintain stability, even if one module is in the midst of crashing.

Let's say I've got several modules that run independently of the shell. Think of a shell replacement--apps and processes running inside a master process.

Here are my three questions:

Let's say I've got a bad module that throws an exception that isn't caught anywhere.  What happens to my program?  Does it still run or did that one module take down the whole application?

Can I use the module still or do I have to reload it?

Can I unload the module and load a new instance of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism modules are still running (by default) in your standard application context.  An unhandled exception will still take down the app.